# Using Twilio JS client, how can I call to a number entered in the texbox?

Tags: javascript, php, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

In order to make outbound call from browser, I followed "https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls" link, and now I can make outbound browser call to a particular number(Which hardcoded behind).

But If I am entering a number in the text-field, to make call to this number, then how can I do this?
Please help me.

for your reference I have attached the screen-shot.

[Screen to make outbound call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOvNv.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The [Outgoing Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls) sample code already includes the client side JavaScript to grab a phone number from an input field in the webpage and include it as a parameter in the [`connect()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#connect) function:

```
function call() {
    // get the phone number to connect the call to
    params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
```

Specifically this code: `$("#number").val()` gets the value from an input field named `number`.

One the server side, Twilio will take the collection of parameters that you provide to the `connect` function and forward those to the URL you have specified as your TwiML Application URL as simple form-encoded values.  You can use PHP's `$_REQUEST` global function to grab those and dynamically generate a TwiML response:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
}
?>

<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+15555555555">
       <?php echo $numberOrClient ?>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.